# Photo Album Id from the News Feed (Facebook Graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

Is there a way to get a Photo's album ID from Facebook Graph API's news Feed.

This previous SO post:

[Facebook Graph API - get a photos album ID](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6022425/facebook-graph-api-get-a-photos-album-id)

suggested using the FQL table, but my application currently only uses the Graph API and I would like as much as possible for it to remain that way. But it seems even if I do another query about the photo itself I still get no album information.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: and your application is developed in?

Comment: my application is developed in Node.js but I am assuming that should not matter as all my requests are done over HTTP to the Graph API

Comment: +1 for your questions AND comment. It's the first time I see a user asking for a *default* example (using HTTP request) without the help of SDK...etc. Now back to your question, I've tried to search the photo object and it seems there's no reference for the album!! You could try it yourself in the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150294959251729) (this image is from a public album from the [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/facebook) page)